Import variable as dependency from the main YAML schema to a sub-schema
I have a YAML schema splitted in two files. Like this:
main.yaml
type: object
properties:
  a:
    description: variable a
    type: string
  b:
    description: variable b
    $ref: support.yaml

and the support.yaml
type: object
properties:
  c:
    description: variable c
    type: string
  d:
    description: variable d
    type: string

I have the following situation: the variable a in main.yaml is required when the variable d in support.yaml is present. I know there is the keyword dependencies in jsonschema but I am not very familiar with the syntax to referencing things in schema or if this is possible.
Do you know if this is possible or any documentation that could help?

depending on the version you are using, you can do something like this:
Using draft-07

use allOf to wrap your conditional statements, this gives you flexibility to add more conditional statements in the future
require both b and d are present and defined
then require a to be defined

src: https://tour.json-schema.org/content/05-Conditional-Validation/04-if-then-else
# main.yaml
$schema: http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#
$id: https://example.org/schema/main.yaml
type: object
properties:
  a:
    description: variable a
    type: string
  b:
    description: variable b
    $ref: 'support.yaml#'
allOf:
  - if:
      required:
        - b
      properties:
        b:
          properties:
            d: true
    then:
      required:
      - a



# support.yaml
$schema: 'http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#'
$id: 'https://example.org/schema/support.yaml'
type: object
properties:
  c:
    description: variable c
    type: string
  d:
    description: variable d
    type: string


Thanks for the suggestion. I tried the solution and it worked partially, this way I end up with variable d always required, which I want to avoid. Is there anyway to make variable a required only, and only if variable d is present while variable d is not required?

Did you mean b?

The if condition is only executed if and only if b AND d are present. There is no requirement for d to be defined otherwise

I was missing some details while converting your example to my case. Thank you very much for the help.
